# Poker hand pot split rule

Tags: poker-theory, poker-strategy, poker-tools, betting-position, side-pots

I have a simple question about a hand play in poker. Below is the situation:

Player 1 cards - A3
Player 2 cards - AJ

5 cards on table - QQ995

Who wins?

Do we split the pot or there is a winner here?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming this is Texas Hold'em. In Texas Hold'em, you play the best 5-card hand you can, regardless of whether those cards come from your hole cards or the community (board) cards.  That means a player could make a hand with any of these combinations:

- 3 community cards + 2 hole cards
- 4 community cards + 1 hole card
- 5 community cards + no hole cards

Based upon that, the best hand that both players can make is two pair with an ace kicker (QQ99A).  The secondary card in each player's hand does not matter since you cannot play a 6th card as part of your hand.  This means that the pot is split because both players are playing the same 5 cards.

Put another way, if AJ wanted to use their J, the best hand they could make is QQAJ9.  The A3 player's best hand is still QQ99A, and QQAJ9 loses to QQ99A.  This is realistically not going to happen since each player *must* play their best possible hand, but it's simply to demonstrate why the J does not play in the AJ hand (and similarly the 3 does not play from the A3 hand).

Answer (score 0):

here we split the pot based on Five hand rule.
community cards are QQ995 P1-A3 , P2-AJ
arrange the cards based on rule P1-QQ99A and P2-QQ99A
so both players be the winner...in Two pair we need to check only 1 kicker card.

Comment: if you need the how the split logic for all 10 combinations checkout this link..(https://pokerfortress.com/players-have-2-pair-in-poker/ ). based on best 5 hands.